# Changing employment and country with Finnish Blue Card

Tags: germany, resident-permit, residency, blue-card, finland

I am holding EU Blue card from Finland for more than 18 months. I got a job offer from Germany and I satisfy the requirements of Blue Card from Germany. As a specific condition my future company wants me to join orientation training on their HQ in Switzerland starting from 1st of Nov. I will be doing roundtrips from Zurich to Helsinki for two months. Then I will be relocating to Dusseldorf on 1st of January. I know that I need to make a fresh Blue Card application from German embassy. Also I find [following link](https://www.expat.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=809503) very useful about changing coutries while holding blue card.

Here my questions;

1. What is the best timing to apply for the EU Blue Card when you consider my specific situation? I believe I can enter Switzerland with my current Blue Card. So can I delay this application around 1st of Dec. or even after 1st of January?
2. If not, then I apply for German EU blue card as soon as possible. So how long will it take to get my Blue Card? I heard embassy can issue some temporary work permit while I am waiting for new card? but no guarantees.
3. If I get my german EU blue card before 1st of January, what will happen to my residence in Finland, since my children are going to kindergarden, if residency drops they lost their kindergarden. What is the relation between blue card and residency?
4. If I dont get my blue card form Germany after 1st of January, can I rent a house in germany and get a residency so that my children can continue their kindergarden?

Comment: I don't have an answer to all your questions but if anything, I would be more concerned about the status of your Finnish Blue card after your current employment ends. Resigning your job in Finland is more likely to have some consequences (immediately or further down the line) than applying for or being granted a German EU Blue card.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What kind of consequence? I mean law is explicit about possibility to change country and employer after 18m. I did not get what you mean.

Comment: Yes, you can change countries and employers and in fact there seems to be a 3-month grace period allowing you to stay in or return to Finland after expiration. But generally speaking the EU blue card is tied to employment. Once you leave your job, it will eventually expire or become invalid. That — and not the application for the German EU Blue card — is what starts the clock. Think about it that way: If you resign your job and decide that you don't want to apply for an EU Blue card in Germany after all, you would not retain an unlimited right of residence in Finland.

Comment: Now, the 18-month rule is about people coming *to* Finland after a period of stay elsewhere in Europe. But that's not your situation. EU Rules around easy transition between countries ought to make things easier *in Germany* and do not matter much to your status in Finland.

Comment: ok now I get your point. Definitely after I resign there is a 3month period that I need to get a new card. so I think it is better to apply asap.

Comment: May I ask the name of the company ? I have done the same kind of thing in my last job (initial training in Switzerland and then working in Germany). Your new job might be in the same company as the one I worked at, if that's the case I could tell you more about it, you can reach me out at steeven.brunner1@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

If you have a job offer now, you should apply.

Since, I assume, you haven't been working for 24 months job approval by the Job Center must be made

- not sure if this applies if the 24 months have been fulfilled in another country

The start date of the contract should be known

- and if the training time in Switzerland is within the contract period

Independent if it is or not, they could issue it starting when the training starts making moving possible.

A [EU Blue Card FAQs](http://www.bamf.de/EN/Infothek/FragenAntworten/BlaueKarteEU/blaue-karte-eu-node.html) can answer other questions.

Comment: Start date is known and stated in job contract as 1st of Nov and the contract is for unlimited time. I did not understand your 24 month rule and job center. Finiish EU blue card lets me to change country and job after 18m. I guess a similar exist in germany but for 24m. Since I am holding Finnish one and will apply for the german one. I guess 18m is my rule. Other than this can you elloborate on you answer a little bit more. Thanks in advance

Comment: @SemihOzmen after 24 months (in Germany at least) you can change your employer without getting extra permission from the Job Center.

Comment: @SemihOzmen the 18 month rule is also true for Germany. For switching jobs without consent from the Job Center is normally 5 years, for Blue Card holders 2.